If a, b and c satisfy certain conditions ( mod 13 ), find the value of a + b + c ( Mod 13 )
If a,b,c are positive integers less than 13
such that
2ab + bc + ca $\equiv$ 0,
ab + 2bc + ac$\equiv$6abc
ab + bc + 2ca $\equiv$8abc
Find a+b+c mod(13)
This problem has been solved by my textbook the following way -
As 13 is prime, multiply each equation by $(abc)^{-1}$
$2c^{-1} + a^{-1} + b^{-1}$ $\equiv$ 0 (Mod 13)$\longrightarrow$ (1)
$c^{-1} + 2a^{-1} + b^{-1}$ $\equiv$ 6 (Mod 13) $\longrightarrow$ (2)
$c^{-1} + a^{-1} + 2b^{-1}$ $\equiv$ 8 (Mod 13) $\longrightarrow$ (3)
Adding (1), (2) and (3) we get-
$a^{-1} + b^{-1} + c^{-1}$ $\equiv$ 10 (Mod 13)
Further, from ( 1 ) & ( 4 ) we get -
c $\equiv$ 9 (Mod 13)
similarly, we get the remainders when a,b and c are divided by 13, adding them gives us-
3 + 6 + 9 $\equiv$ 5 ( Mod 13 )
My attempt went something like this-
2ab + bc + ac $\equiv$ 0 ( Mod 13 )
ab + 2bc + ac $\equiv$ 6abc ( Mod 13 )
I noticed that you're basically adding bc and subtracting ab from the first equation,
bc - ab $\equiv$ 2abc (mod 13)
we can cancel b from both the sids as b is a positive integer lesser than 13 ( and hence co-prime to 13 ) as mentioned in the question. I obtain three such relations -
c - a $\equiv$ 6ac $\longrightarrow$ (1)
a - b $\equiv$ 2ac $\longrightarrow$ (2)
c - b $\equiv$ 8bc $\longrightarrow$ (3)
Playing around with the systems, I get -
8a $\equiv$ 1 ( Mod 13 )
Trial and error, I get
a $\equiv$ 8 ( Mod 13 )
Similarly,
b $\equiv$ 2 ( Mod 13 )
c $\equiv$ 12 ( Mod 13 )
adding them I get a + b + c $\equiv$ 9 ( Mod 13 )
...
I am clearly wrong here, so my questions are -

Is my approach wrong?
Are my calculations wrong?
Both of the above??

A hint would be appreciated and thanks in advance for the amazing answers!
Source -
This is from "pathfinder olympiad mathematics", solved example 42, number theory.

$8\cdot 8\equiv -1\pmod{13},$ so $a\equiv5\pmod{13},$ not $8.$

@ThomasAndrews Ahhh thanks, I get it now

Wait should I edit the question or delete it?

You should clarify the title. In particular, it seems like you want $2ab+bc+ca \equiv 0 \pmod{13}$, per the writeup.

@CalvinLin I had to squish it in because of the character limit, I'll edit it now thanks!

Please use MathJax.
